# deegree service ExtendedCapabilities XML validation error

Tags: inspire, ows, deegree

I would like to publish INSPIRE compliant WFS service using deegree 3.14.15. deegree is installed using binaries on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I am unable to setup extended capabilities for the WFS service. After uncommenting the proposed extended capabilities section in the example metadata https://schemas.deegree.org/services/metadata/3.4.0/example.xml file I receive a XML validation error.

> Error near line -1, column -1: Premature end of file.

I think that something is wrong with namespaces. I have experimented with different contents of ExtendedCapabilities. Following content returns above-mentioned error

```
<ExtendedCapabilities protocolVersions="2.0.0">
    <inspire_dls:ExtendedCapabilities xmlns:inspire_dls="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_dls/1.0"/> </ExtendedCapabilities>
```

However, if I change the inspire_dls namespace to any other value, validation works e.g.

```
<ExtendedCapabilities protocolVersions="2.0.0">
    <inspire_dls:ExtendedCapabilities xmlns:inspire_dls="http://anyothernamespace.com"/> </ExtendedCapabilities>
```

How can I deal with the problem?

Comment: The following works for me on deegree 3.4.16 `<inspire_dls:ExtendedCapabilities xmlns="http://www.deegree.org/services/metadata" xmlns:inspire_common="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/common/1.0" xmlns:inspire_dls="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_dls/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/common/1.0 http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/common/1.0/common.xsd http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_dls/1.0 http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_dls/1.0/inspire_dls.xsd">`

Comment: Note the inspire schema still exist at an HTTP address

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work. First of all, INSPIRE application schema https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_dls/1.0/inspire_dls.xsd sets the namespace as

> xmlns:inspire_dls="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_dls/1.0"

Secondly, even if I change the schema location to https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_dls/1.0/ I am unable to save the service metadata config file, I receive an error

> Unable to activate resource: Unable to build resource
> OWSMetadataProviderProvider:lcv_metadata: Unable to read service
> metadata config: null

Comment: I have deleted my answer, this answer should be an edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

That error may have different root causes. Please try the following:

1. Check if all deegree configuration files pointing to a INSPIRE schema files do use https as a protocol. Check the issue for more information: https://github.com/deegree/deegree3/issues/1064
2. Upgrade to deegree v3.4.16 containing PR https://github.com/deegree/deegree3/pull/1131
3. Apply the following environment variable to the runtime environment, the Apache Tomcat instance for example by setting: `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl`. See issue https://github.com/deegree/deegree3/issues/1110 for more information.
4. Don't forget to restart Tomcat so that the settings of step 3 are applied.

Comment: Thank you. Now the service metadata file validates. However, when I try to save it I get an error message 
"Unable to activate resource: Unable to build resource OWSMetadataProviderProvider:wfs_metadata: Unable to read service metadata config: null". It also happens when I try to save without editing WFS service metadata from the imported predefined workspace deegree-workspace-inspire

Comment: This may be a bug in the deegree service console. Please report the bug to https://github.com/deegree/deegree3/issues. The only workaround is to reload the workspace over the console and hope that the error disappears. If this doesn't help make the changes directly in the file using a text or XML editor of your choice and reload the workspace again over the console.